# How will I set up Python environment on Azure App Service in Linux OS

Tags: python, azure

I am quite new in Azure web app services. I am having issue with deploying Python web app on Azure (Linux os).

Let's say I have written an application in Python Flask. And I have imported some packages in python. For example, I have imported Flask-mail and I have run `pip freeze` to create requirement.txt file in my IDE where all the packages that I have imported are mentioned.

Now, I created an empty web app on Azure on Azure (by default, the OS will be chosen as Linux If I mention running stack is Python). After this, I deployed my Python application to that Azure web app using Azure cli command from my local machine to Azure server.

How Azure will determine which packages I have used and after that will Azure download those packages while deployment? Or do I need to run the requirement file on azure server explicitly? Is it a good way to run Azure cli command to deploy applications on Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to use Azure Devops to deploy your Flask App, i would recommend you to have a look at [Azure Devops Projects](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/devops-projects/) as this will automatically create the CI/CD pipeline to deploy the solution to Web app.

If you want to explore step by step have a look at this [lab](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/python/), which explains on each step clearly. The requirement.txt will be automatically installed using the pip install command using the Task

Follow this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python?tabs=bash) if you want to manually deploy

Comment: see i dont have much idea on azure devops, i am just beginner in azure. I have small flask app which I need to deploy on azure web app. I have used flask_mail package in that and i mentioned about that package in requirements.txt. But, after deploying it using azure cli (az webapp up)  i found out that on azure its throwing error "flask_mail module not found". I think i am doing some mistake while deploying.

Comment: i see, install the dependencies manually in that case. you can install the packages with kudu